# Open source package for reading BigTIFF format

Tags: image-processing, gis, tiff, large-files, geotiff

I need a free program or library for cropping a huge Geo TIFF file. It is in BigTIFF format. *libtiff doesn't support the format*.

Linux or Windows OS.

Comment: A tiff file has geodata?  Look for a free 64-bit operating system.  It's there.

Comment: Free program or library? If you just need a program to crop it, download http://xpda.com/photomud, disable undo (Tools, Options, Edit), and crop. It will handle larger than 20K x 10k. (Disclosure: it's mine, and as is.)

Comment: @Hans Passant - for you reputation I am surprised you post such meaningless comments.

Comment: @Ross - everybody is entitled to post meaningless or hard to interpret comments.  You too.  Only answers count here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [GDAL's `gdal_translate`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html):

```
gdal_translate -projwin $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2 $infile.tif $outfile.tif
```

In the package gdal-bin under Debian Linux (squeeze or higher).